# How to Group SQL result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data in database

```
MAILFROM, MAILTO , TIMESTAMP, MESSAGE
A B   2013-07-01 12:11:12, Hi
B A   2013-07-01 12:12:12, Hi back
A B   2013-07-01 12:13:12, How are you
A C   2013-07-01 12:14:12, Hi there
D A   2013-07-01 12:16:12, Hi
C D   2013-07-01 12:17:12, Hi
```

How do I group this with select so I get

A C 'comment occurs 3 times

```
SELECT MAILFROM, MAILTO FROM messages WHERE 'A' IN(FROM,TO) GROUP BY FROM
```

gives

A C
as well as 
C A but I want combination combined together.

that it only shows A C 3 times

The example is a mailbox.

This contains:

```
MAILFROM, MAILTO , TIMESTAMP, MESSAGE
A B   2013-07-01 12:11:12, Hi
B A   2013-07-01 12:12:12, Hi back
A B   2013-07-01 12:13:12, How are you
A C   2013-07-01 12:14:12, Hi there
D A   2013-07-01 12:16:12, Hi
C D   2013-07-01 12:17:12, Hi
```

SQL listing should list this (unique conversations)

```
B   2013-07-01 12:13:12, "Hi"  ' Remark Timestap of the latest message
C   2013-07-01 12:14:12, "Hi there"
D   2013-07-01 12:16:12, "Hi"
C D   2013-07-01 12:17:12, "Hi" ' THIS SHOULD NOT BE SHOWN
```

This means this sql will list the messages he have as sender and as receiver (from,to). It should only list between this person and the one sent to no matter who is MAILFROM or MAILTO. timestamp is the date of the latest message between them... Remark he never send to D, a is listed anyhow, to C he sent but didn not get back anything... between B is 3 messages. so output should be only these 3 rows..

Comment: i see A -> C only twice

Comment: read about [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @mnagel the third is `C -> A` he said: `A C as well as C A`

Comment: Please change the name of your fields, this is kinda hard to read, and actually I would be amazed if your query ran as such...

Comment: watch out FROM and TO are reserved words in sql, that only makes confusion.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I changed the description of problem, Mysql

Answer (score 4):

Many databases support the `least()` and `greatest()` functions.  You can do what you want as:

```
select least("from", "to") as party1,
       greatest("from", "to") as party2,
       count(*) as NumMessages,
       max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
from messages
group by least("from", "to"), greatest("from", "to") ;
```

The following uses the `case` isntead (standard SQL) and should work in most databases:

```
select (case when "from" < "to" then "from" else "to" end) as party1,
       (case when "from" < "to" then "to" else "from" end) as party2,
       count(*) as NumMessages,
       max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
from messages
group by (case when "from" < "to" then "from" else "to" end),
         (case when "from" < "to" then "to" else "from" end)
```

EDIT:

If you want this as unique messages for a given person:

```
select (case when "from" = const.ThePerson then "to" else "from" end) as Other,
       count(*) as NumMessages,
       max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
from messages m cross join
     (select 'A' as ThePerson) const
where const.ThePerson in ("from", "to")
group by "from", "to";
```

To get the last message, you need to join back in the original data:

```
select Other, NumMessages, MaxTimeStamp, m.message
from (select (case when "from" = const.ThePerson then "to" else "from" end) as Other,
             count(*) as NumMessages,
             max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp,
             max(ThePerson) as ThePerson,
      from messages m cross join
           (select 'A' as ThePerson) const
      where const.ThePerson in ("from", "to")
      group by "from", "to"
     ) t join
     messages m
     on m."from" in (t.Other, t.ThePerson) and
        m."to" in (t.Other, t.ThePerson) and
        m.TimeStamp = t.maxtimestamp
```

Comment: which are all the dbs support least() and greatest() functions ?

Comment: I changed the description of problem

Comment: Very new to me and nice to know, but I dont think this will list the mailbox as supposed to :P

Answer (score 0):

I made another table with the fields from1 and to1

```
SELECT from1, to1 FROM messages
WHERE (from1 LIKE 'A' AND to1 LIKE 'C') OR (from1 LIKE 'C' AND to1 LIKE 'A')
```

Output

```
A C
C A
A C
```

Comment: I changed the description of problem

Comment: AC and CA should be grouped together

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct (FROM+TO) as ans from messages
```

In MySQL

```
select distinct CONCAT(FROM, '', TO) as ans from messages
```

or

```
select CONCAT(FROM, '', TO) as ans from messages group by CONCAT(FROM, '', TO)
```

Comment: I changed description of problem

Comment: This works well, but i receive then
A B   2013-07-01 12:11:12, Hi
B A   2013-07-01 12:12:12, Hi back
A C   2013-07-01 12:14:12, Hi there
D A   2013-07-01 12:16:12, Hi
C D   2013-07-01 12:17:12, Hi
B-A i dont want... that should be included into row of A-B,

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was the solution

```
select mailfrom, mailto,timestamp from (select MAILFROM,MAILTO,timestamp  from messages union all select MAILTO,MAILFROM,timestamp from messages order by timestamp desc) as MSG where MSG.mailfrom='A' group by MSG.mailto order by bb.timestamp desc
```

Thanks for your time and help, also knows as facebook style of mailbox. I dont know if this is efficient, maybe it would be better to have own mailbox between two users. A_B and B_A have its own and when A write to B then message is added to the string in A_B and B_A mailboxes and then a easy select find conversations select mailbox from message order by timestamp desc.. maybe it would be a faster and more efficient...